# Vigenere cypher (CS50) — what's wrong?

Tags: c, vigenere, cs50

Been working on this for quite sometime now and nothing seems to work. I need to make a Vigenere cypher which takes in a key word as argy[1] and then get a string and using those two, do what a Vigenere cypher does in which the letters A and a in the keyword correspond to a shift of 0 and z and Z correspond to a shift of 25. Cases (upper and lower) must be preserved and any non alphabetical character in the string must not be enciphered and as such the letters in the keyword itself should not be used up until the next alphabetical character is there. That's the basic rundown...

I will post my code. Please don't focus on the actual math behind the problem (I can figure that part out myself) but rather the use of modulus and my loops. Right now I'm only working on the if the character in the string is lowercase case.

The program compiles and seems to work with single letter combination whereas with an argv[1] of 'b' and a string 'a' the output is 'b'. However two letter keywords produce more enciphered letters then letters within the string (how do I fix this). Also, I'm having a hard time with getting the keyword to wrap around to the first letter when it has used up all its letters (in the case where the are more alphabetical characters in the string then the key word).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
int a  = argc;    

if (a != 2)
{
    return 1;    
}

string b = argv [1]; 
int c = strlen(b);
string m;

for (int d = 0; d < c; d++)
{
    if ( isdigit(b[d]) || ispunct(b[d]) || isspace(b[d]) )
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

    m = GetString(); 

for (int i = 0, n = strlen(m); i < n; i++)
{
    if (islower(m[i]))
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= c; j++)
        {                      
            if (j > c)                
            {
                j = 1;  
                printf("%c", ((m[i]+(b[j]))%26)+85);
            } 
            else
            {
                printf("%c", ((m[i]+(b[j]))%26)+85);
            }                                 
        }
    }
  }              
}
```

Comment: post the definitions for `GetString, string`. and sample input with intended output

Comment: A string is the course developed datatype in which you can input anything into so: "this is a string, is a string 1234." <--- thats a string 

GetString is a function to get a string.   Sample input (key word= abc) string= abcd   result should be aced

Thats the best I can do, from my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the looping of the key I think. The Vingenere cipher uses each character of the input key to select an alphabet that has been rotated by that key characters amount (ie: starts with that character). You are looping over the data but for each data character you also loop over all the key characters where you should just be selecting the next one and treating the key as a circular buffer of offset indexes.
You also need to fix your indentation and select sensible variable names. I've appended a working version. I don't see the milage in typedefing `const char *` to `string`. This isn't C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *key = argv[1];
    const char *data = argv[2];
    int keylen, datalen, keyindex = 0;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: vig keystring data\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* validate the key */
    keylen = strlen(key);
    for (int n = 0; n < keylen; n++)
    {
        if ( isdigit(key[n]) || ispunct(key[n]) || isspace(key[n]) )
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid char in key at index %d\n", n);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* iterate over the data adding a key dependent offset*/
    datalen = strlen(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < datalen; i++)
    {
        if (islower(data[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", ((data[i] + key[keyindex]) % 26) + 85);
            /* treat key as circular buffer */
            ++keyindex;
            keyindex %= keylen;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Testing this out:

```
C:\Code>vig abc abcd
aced
```